# Should I delete old tables from Realm on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

As part of an update, I retired a class that was persisted to Realm. These objects could potentially take up a lot of space on users' devices, so I don't want the old objects' data to remain in the Realm file after the migration. Will the Realm migration detect that the class is no longer in the project and do some cleanup, or do I need to explicitly delete that table? In the latter case, how do I do that?

Comment: How do you delete objects while their class is still in your project?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly delete all of the data for the type from the Realm file during the migration. You can do so by calling [`Migration.deleteData(forType:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration10deleteDataFT7forTypeSS_Sb) within your migration block.